# QEMU aarch64 not hitting breakpoint

Tags: linux, kernel, qemu, arm64

I am using QEMU, buildroot-2018.02.6 and Linux kernel (4.18.14), compiled all these on Ubuntu for aarch64, using gdb-multiarch to debug, but not hitting the break point in kernel code; when I set break point, I get below message:

```
warning: Breakpoint address adjusted from 0xffff000008f90990 to 0xff000008f90990.
Breakpoint 1 at 0xff000008f90990: file init/main.c, line 532.
```

Never hit the break point, tried with both `hbreak` and `break`. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which gdb version are you using? There was a bug in gdb in this area in gdb 8.1: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23127 -- it has been fixed in newer gdb version I think, and it wasn't present in older ones like gdb 7.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I tried with gdb with this fix. it didn't work. but it worked on another old machine which has gdb 7.7.1 version.  is there any way to install older version of gdb ?  as I am not able to compile older gdb on my machine as it has latest gcc tools.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see newer version of gdb 8.2 is released which has gdb-multiarch 8.2 version.  it works now. before I didn't compile gdb 8.2 source code for gdb-multiarch, that was the reason it was failing.